# Trying ElementaryOS - boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

First of all I'm not familiar with Linux products, but I'm interested and wanted to try elementary due to fact it looks simple and no additional apps are required after installation - it is like out of the box solution for me.

I did follow the instllation instructions provided on elementary website:
- downloaded rufus
- downloaded elementary and checked .iso
- created bootable USB

Next step was to boot from USB and I had to choose what to do:
On screen there was 4 options to choose, main two were TRY elemntary and INSTALL elementary. So I did choose TRY.
And here comes the problem. Elementary "e" pulsing logo appeared and...nothing happened. I left my laptop for around 30 mins and still nothing.
I did try the same method with ubuntu and same as before "ubuntu" logo appeared and nothing more...

Any clues what to do?

My computer is ASUS GL552VW with Win10 installed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop has a 6th gen intel processor, kaby lake architecture.
the current elementary OS freya 0.3.2 has kernel 3.x i don't know the specific one out of my head.(feel free to add comment) this processor has no drivers in this linux kernel version.

Loki uses linux kernel 4.4 or 4.0.4 something like that. as far as i can find support in 4.0.4 and 4.4 is **not** present.
what i can find is in 4.5 or higher has intel kaby lake support.

what you can do is compile your own kernel pick current RC release.
but due to the post you wrote, i assume you are not a developer or technical capable (correct me if i am wrong) to do so.

The only thing you can do is wait for elementary is using an kernel version that has kaby lake support. Maybe loki will get a new hardware stack (update). Depending on the kernel update would be loki or the release after loki, that the asus is able to run elementary.

that it is loading the boot logo means the kernel is busy trying to start up.
There are ways to look at the output. read this post how to do so https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up.

in these logs you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. I'm sorry for a late answer, but today I'm on a business trip and I will be back tomorrow. You did assume correctly that I do not have knowledge to compile or something to...uh I do not really understand that to be honest :) I will try to boot elementary on other PC then. Thanks again for help, I will wait than for next version of elementary to try it on my laptop.